# Publish From VS to Azure Gives Generic Error

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

Until recently, I had a web solution that I could publish to my Azure webservice from VS2019 without issues. I just got a new PC, and now I get an error message even though the publish seems to work. Something's erroring, but I can't figure out what. I've tried on both VS2019 and VS2022.

When I publish, I get the following error in VS:

> An error has occurred

> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

There are no errors in the output window. In fact, the Output window says "Publish Succeeded" and "Web App was published successfully." And if I look at the live website, it does indeed have my changes.

The fact that there's an error is concerning though, and I don't know how to find more details. I'm worried something in the process isn't completing successfully. Normally VS opens the live website in Chrome after successfully publishing, but it doesn't do so in this case.

What might be the problem? Or what logs can I look at to view more info about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To check the recent releases of VS 2019 & VS 2022, created the web apps and published to Azure App Service - worked successfully:

[image]

Earlier, I also faced similar kind of issues when publishing the Azure Functions Projects, Web Applications to the Azure Services where I has observed the few things to recheck and publish again. Those worked for me every time when I got up these issues.

And When I got this error, it will show the path (like `C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5775.tmp` to see diagnostic log which doesn't help me much.

**Check the below Steps to find the root cause of that error**:

1. Check your `.csproj` framework version is same in the Properties of the project on VS IDE.
2. **`Update`** the **`VS IDE`** either **`2019`** or **`2022`** to the latest release > **`Clean`** the Solution > **`Rebuild`** > **`Run`** Locally > **`Publish`** to Azure.
3. The Priority cause for this error is **`VS IDE Timeout limit`** on the release mode. If the ***internet speed is poor*** or ***unstable*** or ***Server is slow*** or ***Server timeout***, then this issue will occur most probably.
4. Even if the project size is large and if the VS IDE takes more time in release mode, then also there might be a chance of this error occurrence.

Still if the issue persists, raise the ticket in GitHub Repository of [Azure App Service-VSIDE](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A####%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID:%2064e750b6-a84d-c665-9bb3-167241a33d10%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID:%20f22f673f-469c-e137-304b-aa92662e0790%0A*%20Content:%20%5BQuickstart:%20Deploy%20an%20ASP.NET%20web%20app%20-%20Azure%20App%20Service%5D%28https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs%29%0A*%20Content%20Source:%20%5Barticles/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore.md%5D%28https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore.md%29%0A*%20Service:%20**app-service**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login:%20@cephalin%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias:%20**cephalin**)